# How to layout subviews on device rotation

Tags: ios, iphone, button, interface-builder

This view, with a series of buttons, is properly designed for portrait, but not for landscape.

[image: portrait]
http://luigidaddario.it//iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%2029.dic.2013%2022.15.55.png

[image: landscape]
http://luigidaddario.it//iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%2030.dic.2013%2020.10.13.png

How do I lay it out properly for both landscape and portrait?

Comment: what do you mean? ;) the problem is that the buttons are disordered in landscape mode.

Comment: @user3147603 Are you using auto-layout?

Comment: no... but i tried to use autolayout...,

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have added buttons using auto-sizing masks (though the mask for the lower left yellow button might be missing). You have at least two approaches you could adopt:

1. In your view controller's [`viewWillLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW90), programmatically set the `frame` of each of the buttons according to where it would be for that orientation. For example, if you had an array of buttons, you could do something like:

   ```
   - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
   {
       NSInteger cols, rows;

       if (self.view.bounds.size.width < self.view.bounds.size.height)
       {
           cols = 3;
           rows = 4;
       }
       else
       {
           cols = 4;
           rows = 3;
       }

       CGFloat pixelsWide = self.view.bounds.size.width / cols;
       CGFloat pixelsTall = self.view.bounds.size.height / rows;

       for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 11; i++)
       {
           UIView *view = self.buttons[i];

           NSInteger row = floor(i / cols);
           NSInteger col = i % cols;

           view.center = CGPointMake((col + 0.5) * pixelsWide,
                                     (row + 0.5) * pixelsTall);
       }
   }
   ```

   [image: rotation]

   (If using auto layout, rather than setting the frame, you'd set the appropriate constraint. But you said that you're not using auto layout.)
2. Rather than adding these buttons to your view yourself, you could use a [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html), which will take care of the placement of the cells appropriate for the orientation. It might be overkill for this sort of situation, but when you want to layout a view into a series of cells, a collection view is a great alternative. See [UIKit User Interface Catalog: Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UICollectionView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UICollectionView).

Comment: Thank you ;) ... but i have a problem with this: 'UIView *view = self.buttons[i];' . it gives me error. (Property 'buttons' not found on object of type 'FirstViewController'

Comment: @LuigiDaddario This was just an example, but you obviously have to tailor it to match however you reference your buttons (e.g. `IBOutlet` references?). The key message is that you should be programmatically changing the `frame` or the `center` properties of your individual buttons in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method